# Standardizing string comparison syntax using Find & Replace

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace, visual-studio-2013

I would like to standardize the syntax used when comparing two strings within a C# file. So I'd like to use Visual Studio 2013's Find & Replace feature to alter the syntax used to compare a string literal to a string variable.

For examples, I would like the following replacements to be made.

- `"something".Equals( myStr )` becomes `myStr == "something"`
- `"something".Equals( myObj.myStr )` becomes `myObj.myStr == "something`"
- `myStr.Equals( "something" )` becomes `myStr == "something"`
- `myObj.myStr.Equals( "something" )` becomes `myObj.myStr == "something`"

I cannot make any assumptions as to the specific string literals used or how the variables are named. What is the regular expression syntax that makes this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do two replaces for each of the different types of strings:

```
("[^"]+")\.Equals\(\s+(\S+)\s+\)
```

Replace with `$2 == $1` for the first two types.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hD9aS2).

And:

```
(\S*?)\.Equals\(\s+("[^"]+")\s+\)
```

Replace with `$2 == $1` for the second two types.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wD1sK5)

Comment: Nice! I was almost done manually replacing but this way is way cooler.  It didn't work for negation, but maybe next time.

Comment: @HappyNomad Well, the regex is specifying `.Equal` to be in the match, that might be why. Now that you know, you can change that bit to adapt the regex to your requirements.